# Suddenly cannot import a python file for pytest using classes

Tags: python, oop, import, pytest, importerror

I was checking a similar problem about importing python files and it seems like something to do with my `_init_.py` file in the main parent folder a level up from my tests folder (which contains all my test files) for importing classes, but not sure. Maybe it is nothing to do with this.

I am using `pytest` for testing and want to group multiple tests into a class that helps me test the parsing of multiple sentences: http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/getting-started.html#grouping-multiple-tests-in-a-class.

Now, when from another file which is in the same folder (`test_pipelines.py`), I try and run `import test_text` I am unable to do this. Why is this so?

The main issue here is this statement `from test_text import UNEMPLOYMENT_SENTENCES` within `test_pipelines.py` is not even picking up the file `test_text`, let alone`UNEMPLOYMENT_SENTENCES` within it.

**Contents of test_text.py**

```
UNEMPLOYMENT_SENTENCES = [
    "The number of people out of work in Brazil is 2% of the population",
    "2% of Brazil is out of work",
    "2% of Brazil's citizens are jobless",
    "About 9% of Brazil's citizens are out of work or looking for jobs",
    "Brazil is in trouble; it has an unemployment rate of 7%",
    "Brazil is facing issues - it has an unemployment % of 6%"
]

def test_sample_sentences():
    """
    :param sentence_array: array
    :return: tests all sentences with 3 tests
    """

    for sentence in UNEMPLOYMENT_SENTENCES:
        doc = Text(sentence)
        test_instance = UnemploymentTestClass(doc)
        test_instance.sentence_tokenization()
        test_instance.entities()
        test_instance.claim_candidates()

class UnemploymentTestClass:

    def __init__(self,s):
        """
        Initiates a test sentence
        """
        self.s=s

    ....What follows is a list of functions that call self as an argument but don't contain 'test' at the front for pytest. e.g. def sentence_tokenization(self),  def entities(self), def claim_candidates(self), using self.s as a parameter to play with.


class ComplexTestClass:
    """
    Complex and more nuanced tests for specific sentences
    """
   ...Note, these are all @staticmethod functions which start with the word 'test_' e.g. def test_multiple_sentences().... so pytest can pick them up.
```

Answer (score 0):

The file `__init__.py` is used to structure your modules and group them.

If you place your `test_text.py` in the same folder where you have the script that imports it, there should not be any problems. In case your `test_text.py` is in a subfolder I would recommend to add the `__init__.py` file.

This is how a package structure would look like:

```
sound/                          Top-level package
      __init__.py               Initialize the sound package
      formats/                  Subpackage for file format conversions
              __init__.py
              wavread.py
              wavwrite.py
              aiffread.py
              aiffwrite.py
              auread.py
              auwrite.py
              ...
      effects/                  Subpackage for sound effects
              __init__.py
              echo.py
              surround.py
              reverse.py
              ...
      filters/                  Subpackage for filters
              __init__.py
              equalizer.py
              vocoder.py
              karaoke.py
              ...
```

Inside the `__init__.py` you can declare vars like `__all__ = ["echo", "surround", "reverse"]` which will import all submodules that you specify wen `from sound.effects import *`

PS: I have copied your code and did not have any problem to import it from the same folder.

PS2: source: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages

Piece of code that works for me when i place prueba.py (your code snippet) in the same folder as the scripts that imports it.

```
from prueba import UnemploymentTestClass
a = UnemploymentTestClass("asd")
print a.s

# print result
# asd
```

Comment: Hi @Manuel the import is from the same folder as `test_text.py` so this is not the issue. I think the problem may be to do with my classes.

Comment: try to do:  `from file import Class`, also you can add this line of code to the `__init__.py` and modify the `__all__` var so it looks like `__all__ = ["Class1", "Class2"]`

Comment: I want all classes (what you call modules) ideally to be imported when I import `test_text.py` from `test_pipelines.py`. i.e. `UnemploymentTestClass`, `ComplexTestClass` and `UNEMPLOYMENT_SENTENCES`. The `UNEMPLOYMENT_SENTENCES` fixed variable is most important but specifying specific ones isn't that important. The main issue here is just this statement `from test_text import UNEMPLOYMENT_SENTENCES` is not even picking up `test_text`, let alone `UNEMPLOYMENT_SENTENCES` within it.

Comment: Using the code snippet you copied above this piece of code seems to work for me (see the edit in the answer)

Comment: Can you share more details about the error you are getting?